# How to setup debugging for the system under test in unit testing?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, unit-testing, moq

**How do you set up debugging so that you can step through your system under test code?**

I've got this test:

```
    [Test]
    public void GetDeviceSettings_is_called()
    {
        //Arrange
        var mockDeviceInteractions = new Mock<IDeviceInteractions>();
        mockDeviceInteractions.SetupSet(p => p._settingsFileQueue = It.IsAny<string>());
        mockDeviceInteractions.Setup(x => x.GetDeviceSettings(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>()));
        //Act
        mockDeviceInteractions.Object._settingsFileQueue = @"C:\";
        mockDeviceInteractions.Object.GetDeviceSettings("123123", "dfgdfg");
        //Assert
        mockDeviceInteractions.VerifyAll();
    }
```

and here's the method I'm acting on:

```
public virtual DeviceSettings GetDeviceSettingsForSerialNumber(string serial) {

 //do stuff - and i've put a break point here, but it does not step at the break point
GetDeviceSettings(string1, string2);
//do more stuff
    }
```

**What am I doing wrong? Why does it not stop at the breakpoint?**

Comment: It doesn't stop because **you're not using the `DeviceInteractions` class** - you're using a mocked version of it.

Comment: but in that case i would not be able to use any of the moq features like setup and verifyall right?

Comment: You would be able to use those features as you have created a Mock and have mocked the `GetDeviceSettingsForSerialNumber` as this `virtual`. In the background `Moq` is creating an overridden method for you which you are then calling which doesn't do anything. Plus `VerifyAll` won't verify anything as you haven't setup any verification's.

Comment: If you want to actually test `GetDeviceSettingsForSerialNumber` but setup `GetDeviceSettings` simply remove the `Setup(... GetDeviceSettingsForSerialNumber)` call.

Comment: Very confusing what you actually trying to test... Maybe you should refactor your code to have dependencies injected into your class instead of providing them in overrides of virtual functions?

Comment: thank you guys for your feedback. i've updated the test, and my question remains: Why does it not stop at the breakpoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the question,

> How do you set up debugging so that you can step through your system under test code?

There is no particular setup that you have to do that would be any different from debugging a system running from the `Start` button in Visual Studio.

A unit test is effectively just code that stresses the **`public`** API of a `class`. The only difference between the unit test and an actual call to the public API is the fact that you have some `attributes` to add to the method and that you `mock` dependencies within the class.
The class itself remains the same as it does when debugging normally but you have setup scenarios for it to handle different logic which you can then `verify` occurred correctly.

To get your test runner to run the test in `debug` you'll have to select it to run in `debug` otherwise most runners default to running in what is basically `release` mode. Depending on the runner that you are using this is accomplished differently, but most usually allow you to `right-click` the test to `debug` and select something along the lines of `Debug the selected Tests`.

Addressing your next question,

> What am I doing wrong? Why does it not stop at the breakpoint?

When you are running a unit test as described above you are testing the actual class but are setting up scenarios that the logic implemented must handle correctly.

The main issue is that you don't look as though you are ever calling the method you are expecting to run, the test never calls `GetDeviceSettingsForSerialNumber(...)` unless this is called by the setting of the property which you haven't described.

What you have actually done is to mock the system under test therefore not actually testing the implemented code, but basically testing that `moq` works correctly. This can be identified by this line:

```
mockDeviceInteractions.Setup(x => x.GetDeviceSettings(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>()));
```

You are mocking the call to `GetDeviceSettings(string, string)`, I'm not sure on the implementation of this method but if the method is marked as `virtual` `moq` will in the background create a new overridden method which will be called when **any** `string` is provided as the arguments.

You are then calling:

```
mockDeviceInteractions.Object.GetDeviceSettings("123123", "dfgdfg");
```

`moq` in the background is receiving this call and the interceptor is matching this to one of the setup calls (see above), it will then call the setup call which neither does anything nor returns anything.

If the method you are trying to test 'GetDeviceSettingsForSerialNumber' is called when the property (I hope this isn't a field you are calling) is set this is nullified when you setup the property with the call:

```
mockDeviceInteractions.SetupSet(p => p._settingsFileQueue = It.IsAny<string>());
```

I've never attempted this but I don't believe that it will run the actual property setter in the class which may be what you are looking for.

If you wanted to setup the property to have default value you are able to say:

```
mock.SetupProperty(f => f.Name, "foo");
```

Now I could explain why I feel that what you are testing is incorrect, but I feel that @stuartd answer covers how a `class` should be structured in having dependencies which you can mock to return data instead of mocking calls within the system under test. I will instead show you how I would structure your actual test with the structure you have just now.

```
[Test]
public void GetDeviceSettings_is_called()
{
    //Arrange
    var mockDeviceInteractions = new Mock<IDeviceInteractions>();
    var deviceSettings = new Mock<IDeviceSettings>();
    mockDeviceInteractions.Setup(x => x.GetDeviceSettings(@"123123", "dfgdfg"))
        .Returns(deviceSettings.Object)
        .Verifiable();

    //Act
    var actual = mockDeviceInteractions.Object.GetDeviceSettingsForSerialNumber(@"123123");

    //Assert
    Assert.Equal(deviceSettings.Object, actual);
    mockDeviceInteractions.Verify();
}
```

First off I have removed you `SetupSet` for the property, this is not required, if you want to set the actual property just set it on the object, I also removed the property being set as I couldn't see how this fit in with your test, unless you are expecting that method to be called from the property setter which you haven't described.

Next up I have added a `Returns` method call to your `Setup` of the `GetDeviceSettings`, I wasn't sure what this returned but as you can see it returns a `IDeviceSettings` in my example and I have also marked this as `Verifiable`.

I then call the actual `GetDeviceSettingsForSerialNumber` from thee object. You never called this at all so I'm not surprised that you couldn't hit a breakpoint.

Finally I am asserting that the `IDeviceSettings` returned from the call is the same as the one that the `GetDeviceSettings` method returned. I know this is slightly different from your implementation as you return a concrete `DeviceSettings` but this should actually return an `interface`.

Lastly I am verifying the `mockDeviceInteractions` as you can see with the `Verify` call and not the `VerifyAll` call as I occasionally setup a mock with calls that I don't necessary want to `Verify` and only the mark the ones that I do want to `Verify` with the correct method call.

Comment: Thank you Stephen... I have seen the light

Comment: could you please explain what this does: Assert.Equal(deviceSettings.Object, actual);

Comment: `Assert.Equal(object, object)` checks that the actual object is the same as the expected object. So it could be used like `Assert.Equal(3, Add(1, 2))`, I'm expecting the result will be 3 and the actual result presented is the result of the `Add(1, 2)` call. As we all know that if you add 1 and 2 you expect the result to be 3. This can also be used with objects to make sure that they are the same which is how I was using this in the example.

Answer (score 2):

You must mock ***the objects which will be called*** by the class under test, not the class itself.

Here's an example. It assumes you can inject dependencies into your classes.

Imagine you are writing a nuclear control system. You want to check that the system will instruct the reactor to perform an emergency shutdown when it needs to, by writing a unit test.

```
public enum ReactorStatus { Ok, OhDear};

public interface IReactorInteractions {
    ReactorStatus ShutDown(bool nicely);
    ReactorStatus Status { get; }
}

public interface ICore {
    ReactorStatus ShutDown(bool nicely);
    ReactorStatus GetStatus();
}

public class ReactorInteractions : IReactorInteractions {

    private ICore reactor;
    public ReactorInteractions(ICore reactor) {
         this.reactor = reactor;
    }

    public ReactorStatus ShutDown(bool nicely) {
          return reactor.ShutDown(nicely);
    }

    public ReactorStatus Status { 
     get { return reactor.GetStatus(); } 
    }
}
```

So, you want to test the ReactorInteractions class.

In order to do this, then, you mock the object that it calls, in this case `ICore`. **You do not want to perform operations on the actual Core.** Doing so would surely be a disciplinary offence, at the very least!

You should pass the `Object` property of the `ICore` mock as the constructor parameter to the ReactorInteractions class - this property is not something that you should be accessing in your test, it is designed solely to be passed to the class under test - it is this 'Object' that the class under test acts on, allowing you to use `Setup` and `Verify`:

```
private Mock<ICore> mockCore;
private IReactorInteractions reactor;

[SetUp]
public void TestSetup() {
    mockCore = new Mock<ICore>();
    reactor = new ReactorInteractions(mockCore.Object);
}
```

So some example tests (which if they were real tests would be validating and checking worthwhile things - tests should check *logic*, not plumbing.):

```
[Test]
public void ShutDown_Nicely_Should_Pass()  {
    mockCore.Setup(m => m.ShutDown(true).Returns(ReactorStatus.Ok));
    var status = reactor.ShutDown(true);
    status.Should().Be(ReactorStatus.Ok);
    mockCore.VerifyAll();
}

[Test]
public void ShutDown_Badly_Should_Fail()  {
    mockCore.Setup(m => m.ShutDown(false).Returns(ReactorStatus.OhDear));
    var status = reactor.ShutDown(false);
    status.Should().Be(ReactorStatus.OhDear);
    mockCore.VerifyAll();
}
```

Note that I am not using `It.IsAny<bool>` in my test setup. This syntax is verry confusing for developers new to mocking (seen in the wild: trying to use `It.IsAny` as parameters in test calls) - which is something that I wish the Moq author would highlight in the documentation. **It.IsAny should only be used if you have absolutely no control over the parameter.**

In your case, there's no need to use `It.IsAny` - *you know exactly what values you're going to pass*:

```
const string serial = "123456";
mockDeviceInteractions.Setup(m => m.GetDeviceSettingsForSerialNumber(string serial))
                      .Returns(new DeviceSettings { Serial = serial };

var settings = classUnderTest.GetDeviceSettingsForSerialNumber(serial);
settings.Serial.Should.Be(serial);
```

Then in the test, you are checking that *the actual value is used*. If you test for `It.IsAny` then bear in mind that the part of your code that deals with that value could be replaced with a random number generator and the unit test would still pass.

Having said that, Moq  has had the limitation that if one argument in the list is unknown and must use `It.IsAny` then they all must be (I'm not using it any more so I don't know if that's still the case, but I seem to remember you could work around that anyway by using a callback to validate the parameters manually)

Comment: Learned a ton from this post. Thank you so much